# How to expire a php session after certain time?

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

I have the following code:

The page Login.php

```html
<?PHP
      session_start();
      include("conexion.php");
      $conn = conexion();
      extract($_POST);

      $password = md5($pass);
      echo $password;
      $sql1="Select * from miembro where user='".$user."'and pass ='".$password."'";
      $re= mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
     $numrows1 = mysqli_num_rows($re);
      echo $sql1;
      echo $numrows1;
     if ($numrows1==0 or $numrows1>=2){
        $_SESSION['session'] = "no";
      header('Location:' . getenv('HTTP_REFERER'));
     }else{
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($re);
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row["nombre"];
        echo $_SESSION['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['codigo'] = $row["codigo"];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $row["pass"];
        $_SESSION['apellido'] = $row["apellido"];
        $_SESSION['telefono'] = $row["telefono"];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row["user"];
        $_SESSION['cargo'] = $row["cargo"];
        $_SESSION['correo'] = $row["correo"];
        $_SESSION['session'] = "si";
        $_SESSION['last_time'] = time();
        header("Location: ./actions/perfil.php");
      }
    ?>
```

And perfil.php (where the user is taken once logged in)

```html
<?php
 include("./menu_actions.php");
 include("../conexion.php");
 if($_SESSION['session'] != "si"){
  header("location: ../home.php");
 }

 $us = $_SESSION['user'];
    $sql="select * from miembro where user = '$us';";
   echo $sql;
   $query = mysqli_query(conexion(),$sql);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    if((time() - $_SESSION['last_time']) > 10){ //After 10 sec
    header("location:logout.php");
    }
  }
  else{
    header('Location:login.php');
  }

 ?>
 
 //HTML
```

It's not working and I don't understand why. The time of the start of the session is kept in a variable and analyzed later with an if loop, so if the time exceeds 10 seconds, the user should be forced out and taken to the login page again, but I can't make it work. Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes, I think it might be a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe try to set cookie in this way:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 10, "/"); // 86400 is one day
```

then check is it set instead by isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])